# Returning the same UINavigationBar subclass object for all UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to implement a `UINavigationBar` subclass to return a `singleton` in such a way that all my navigation controllers are showing the same navigation bar object?  If so, how do I do it?

I tried subclassing and work the `init(coder: aDecoder)` method, but it's quickly become confusing.  I am using `storyboard` so I believe that forces me to use `init(coder: aDecoder)`.

Comment: Just implement a category for you custom UINavigationBar

Comment: what would the method(s) in that category do to my UINavigationBar?

Comment: What benefit would this singleton provide you?

Comment: it seems logical to me if all my navigation controllers are showing the same navigation bar object that they are actually the same object, hence why, so saves me a little memory but more importantly it seems like the right pattern

Comment: [Here is a blog post that explains how to implement this](http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/09/11/customizing-the-look-of-uinavigationbar-and-uinavigationcontroller/)

Comment: @Lefteris that's not what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway

Comment: Seems like the kind of thing you would put in AppDelegate. You could easily access your NavBar from anywhere with [AppDelegate myNavBar];

Comment: @Alex wouldn't my navigation controllers still instantiate their own navigation bars?  I know I can access a variable from a sibling object if I'm in a larger scope like the app delegate.  I guess I'm just trying to be minimalist by trying to subclass `UINavigationController` or `UINavigationBar` to grab always the same instance of `UINavigationBar`.  Theoretically, I think it should be possible, but I'm having trouble in practice.

Comment: How can you have only one `UINavigationBar`, each page should at least have a different title, different back button and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wander why you need this? Because a `UINavigationBar` is `UIView` and a `UIView` can only has one superview.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to implement a reusable instance of `UIView` or `UINavigationBar`.  I don't think that's so far fetched, or is it?